# Stop display settings changing when turning off DP monitors on Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, xorg, nvidia, displayport

I have Linux Mint Cinnamon 18.3 running with the proprietary drivers from Nvidia. The automatic display detection is great for setting up (way easier than the old days!) but as DisplayPort disconnects monitors when they're turned off, it's moving my windows around on my 3 display setup.

Is there any way to take a snapshot of the currently detected configuration and lock it in xorg to stop things changing and moving my windows around?

Alternatively, is there any way to tell the proprietary driver to ignore power states for the monitor? I'm unaware of the specifics of the DP protocol so not sure if this is an issue.

I had to disable DPMS/ sleep mode for my monitor as it kept crashing on resume so the only other option I have is to leave my monitors on all the time which will waste a lot of power.

Happy to share any configs etc but as it's all auto-detected I wasn't sure that would be much help.

Comment: Automatic display and audio detection/configuration is great, but only when it does what you want. I don't have an answer, but you can write a repair script in bash, etc. using tools like `xrandr` and `xdotool` to put things back where you want them. I have one that fixes my KDE desktop after I start a new session. If you get really fancy, you can detect the device being turned on and off and trigger your script.

Comment: Thanks @Joe, I'll look into those tools. It's a bit of a shame going from one extreme (annoyingly manual) to another (annoyingly automatic) but I guess 2019 will just have to be the year of the linux desktop instead.

Comment: The crazy thing is that *obviously* the driver doesn't move windows around.  The driver doesn't even know about "windows".  It's the DE/WM that does it.  Why these (and this is a problem every DE/WM seems to have) don't have an option that tells them not to do it is really the mystery here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In most cases, the RandR extension is used to configure display settings. Therefore, I will focus on it in this answer. So this answer may not apply if you're using Wayland, the proprietary NVIDIA drivers without [DRM (Direct Rendering Manager) kernel mode setting](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA#DRM_kernel_mode_setting) enabled or have disabled the RandR extensions. If so, calling `xrandr` should result in an error instead of printing the current display configuration.

While `xrandr` does not change the display configuration if you unplug a monitor, your desktop environment does this. Technically, the desktop environment is implementing [an xrandr client which is handling the `XRRScreenChangeNotify` event](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man3/Xrandr.3.html#sect4) and updating your display configuration when a monitor is disconnected.

Depending on your used desktop environment, you can disable this behavior:

**Gnome till 3.1.3**:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xrandr active false
```

This option was to be removed in [newer versions](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-settings-daemon/commit/caf51f50f332aabe7af77f9641ac288dd88af553#diff-8d777f385d3dfec8815d20f7496026dc). Seems to be handled by Mutter now.

**[Cinnamon](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/cinnamon#Prevent_Cinnamon_from_overriding_xrandr/xinput_configuration)**:

Copy `/etc/xdg/autostart/cinnamon-settings-daemon-xrandr.desktop` to `$HOME/.config/autostart`. Then append the line `Hidden=true` to the copied file.

**Cinnamon before 3.4**:

```
gsettings set org.cinnamon.settings-daemon.plugins.xrandr active false
```

**[Mate Desktop](https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-settings-daemon/blob/master/data/org.mate.SettingsDaemon.plugins.xrandr.gschema.xml.in#L4)**:

```
gsettings set org.mate.settings-daemon.plugins.xrandr active false
```

**KDE**

[kscreen](https://community.kde.org/Solid/Projects/ScreenManagement) is managing the display settings in the KDE Plasma 5 desktop. There seems to be no way to disable the auto-plug behavior with a configuration setting. However, you can kill the daemon which is responsible for it `/usr/lib/kf5/kscreen_backend_launcher` to prevent any further changes to your display configuration. Note: The daemon will be restarted when you're launching the KDE display settings.

Comment: Thanks @sven.to. Am trying to get this working correctly on Cinnamon 4.2.4 on Mint 19.2, and have made some progress. After doing as described, then rebooting, if I put a window onto a second monitor and then switch it off and on again, the window still jumps back to the first monitor - *but only the first time I do it*. Doing it again results in the window staying where it's put, even when the monitor is off. Any ideas why this might be? I tried watching the Melange/`cinnamon-looking-glass` log while I do this, but no entries appear (either the first time or subsequent times).

Comment: Oh... windows moved to the second monitor no longer appear on the taskbar/panel either haha.

Comment: Thanks @sven.to. I'm on Cinnamon 4.6.3 on Arch Linux. Your approach was mention got me close, but I encountered issue configuring the display, getting a weird error `XRANDR_2 was not provided by any .service files`. The desktop position was wrong. I realized the `$HOME/.config/monitors.xml` was generated by `csd-xrandr`, If I setup my desktop properly, then kill `csd-xrandr`. It seems to do the trick.

Comment: On Linux Mint 19, Mate, the key was a little different than the one posted.  You can find it by starting with `gsettings get org.mate.` and hitting tab to see the possibilities.  The end result was `gsettings set org.mate.SettingsDaemon.plugins.xrandr active false`

Comment: Whats about Cinnamon 5.6 ?